# Como hacer mas rápido el tiempo de carga en ruby on rails "localhost:3000"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, servidor

Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna forma de que el servidor de `ruby on rails` sea mas rápido, ya que actualmente estoy desarrollando un sitio web en esta tecnología, pero al momento de querer probar mis nuevos cambios se tarda entre 30 segundos y un minuto para poder ver los cambios de nuevo. entonces yo quisiera ver si hay la posibilidad de que todo esto se agilice para no estar esperando tanto tiempo en ver los nuevos cambios.

Inicializo el servidor de ruby desde la `consola de windows` con el comando de `rails s`

Errores que salen en la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cualquier cambio (ya sea _front_ o _back_) tarda en reflejarse?

Comment: @Gerry si cualquier cambio ya sea .css o .js o de cualquier tipo, sea básico o complejo, de echo casi no llevo mucho de mi sitio web, por eso me extraña y pues no se si tenga que ver mi computadora aunque con apache funciona muy rápido.

Comment: ¿Estás reiniciando tu servidor en cada cambio? Esto no es necesario, solo necesitas reiniciar tu servidor para cambios en configuración; cualquier cambio dentro de tu carpeta `app` debe reflejarse inmediatamente (sin reiniciar el servidor).

Comment: @Gerry no, no reinicio el servidor ese lo dejo corriendo todo el tiempo, me refiero a recargar solo la pagina donde estoy trabajando, esa recarga es la que tarda mucho.

Comment: ¿Puedes ver en la consola del navegador qué elementos tardan en cargar?

Comment: @Gerry ya actualice el post, con los errores de consola

Comment: Se ven varios errores de archivos no encontrados, pero no creo que sean el problema (posiblemente el archivo `show_ads.js`); pero para saberlo cambia a la pestaña _Network_ en lugar de _Console_ y ahí podrás ver que está tomando tiempo en cargar.

Comment: Prueba a agregar [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) a tu proyecto, te dará una idea de qué partes de tu código se están demorando más que otras

Comment: Hola yo sufri de lo mismo en Windows, tiene muy mal rendimiento la verdad y no se porque, incluso instale un programa para cachear programas mas usados y los cargue mas rapido y ni asi.... mi solucion fue instalar Linux Ubuntu.... y la diferencia es ABISMAL..!!!! creo que deberias considerar tener Linux como sistema operativo complementario... despues de todo., cuando se pone en produccion, se pone sobre linux saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer una aplicación más rápida, primero debes determinar la causa de que tarde tanto (30 segundos es demasiado) en cargar.

El tiempo que tarda en cargar puede depender de muchos factores. Desde la conexión a la base de datos, la incorporación de css y scripts desde otros sitios.

Primero debes averiguar si el problema está estrictamente en la respuesta del servidor o se trata de otros recursos ajenos al servidor. Revisa el log de rails `log/development.log` para saber exactamente que hace y cuánto tarda en responder a cada petición.

Si usas Chrome puedes recargar la página mientras están en la sección 'network' en las herramientas del desarrollador.

Todo depende de la causa. Los errores que muestras son errores de recursos que no existen o que no te permiten usarlos.